# Conversion warning. and Class error

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, pointers

I'm learning C++, and in an assignment I'm doing right now, I get a bunch of warnings that I suspect are causing the two errors I'm getting as well.  The problem is that the lines where the warnings show up are lines (one of which) he gave us, so I think the code must be right.  This leads me to believe that there is an issue in my class declaration or constructor.  Can anyone spot anything wrong?

The warning (for each line of the fillSystemCommandList function) is 
**Conversion from string literal to 'char *' is deprecated**

and the errors are 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  **"COMMAND::COMMAND(char*, int)", referenced from:**
      fillSystemCommandList() in system_utilities.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: **linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

You can probably skip over the ParseCommandLine function, I think it's all fine.  I just included it so that I could have the entire file (this isn't my main btw.)

Other Notes:
-The systemCommands array is supposed to be of COMMAND pointers of length NUMBER_OF_COMMANDS (I think I did that right)

-the fillSystemCommandList function is supposed to populate the systemCommands array with structures which contain pointers to the command strings and the corresponding defined constants.

-I know that this code is almost all C, and that's again because the class I'm taking is a beginning C++ class.

```
#include "system_utilities.h"
#include "definitions.h"
using namespace std;


int getCommandNumber(char *s);

class COMMAND {
    char* pointertochar;
    int* pointertoint;


public:
    COMMAND(char*, int);
    int amIThisCommand(char*);
};

int COMMAND::amIThisCommand(char* command){
    return 0;
}

COMMAND* systemCommands[NUMBER_OF_COMMANDS];



int parseCommandLine(char cline[], char *tklist[]){
    int i;
    int length; //length of line
    int count = 0; //counts number of tokens
    int toklength = 0; //counts the length of each token
    length = strlen(cline);
    for (i=0; i < length; i++) {   //go to first character of each token

        if (((cline[i] != ' ' && cline[i-1]==' ') || i == 0)&& cline[i]!= '"') {



            while ((cline[i]!=' ')&& (cline[i] != '\0') && (cline[i] != '\r')){
                toklength++;
                i++;
            }
          //---------------
        tklist[count] = (char *) malloc( toklength +1);
        memcpy(tklist[count], &cline[i-toklength], toklength);
        tklist[count][toklength]='\0';
            //cout << "\n" << tklist[count] << "\n";
            //cout << "\n" << i << "\n";
            //cout << "\n" << toklength << "\n";
        //--------------
            count ++;
            toklength = 0;
        }

        if (cline[i] == '"') {
            do {
                toklength++;
                i++;
                /*if (cline[i] == ' ') {
                    toklength--;
                }*/
            } while (cline[i]!='"');

            //--------------
            tklist[count] = (char *) malloc( toklength +1);
            memcpy(tklist[count], &cline[i-toklength+1], toklength-1);
            tklist[count][toklength]='\0';
            //cout << "\n" << tklist[count] << "\n";
            //cout << "\n" << i << "\n";
            //cout << "\n" << toklength << "\n";

            //--------------
            count ++;
            toklength = 0;
        }

    }

    return count;



}

int getCommandNumber(char *s) {

    /*switch (*s) {
       // case "halt":
            return HALT;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }*/
    return 0;

}

void fillSystemCommandList() {

    systemCommands[0] = new COMMAND("halt", HALT);
    systemCommands[1] = new COMMAND("status", STATUS);
    systemCommands[2] = new COMMAND("time_click", TIME_CLICK);
    systemCommands[3] = new COMMAND("new_sensor", NEW_SENSOR);
    systemCommands[4] = new COMMAND("new_sensor_node", NEW_SENSOR_NODE);
    systemCommands[5] = new COMMAND("new_network", NEW_NETWORK);
    systemCommands[6] = new COMMAND("add_sensor_to_node", ADD_SENSOR_TO_NODE);
    systemCommands[7] = new COMMAND("add_node_to_network", ADD_NODE_TO_NETWORK);
    systemCommands[8] = new COMMAND("sensor_command", SENSOR_COMMAND);

}
```

Thanks again for any help that you can give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`systemCommands` is an class of `COMMAND` objects. The `COMMAND` class has member with `char*` type, however: `"halt"` in

```
   systemCommands[0] = new COMMAND("halt", HALT);
```

are of `const char*`, therefore you got that warning message. You did not define the constructor of your `COMMAND` class.

```
  COMMAND(const char*, int); //needs to be defined. note ptr is const
```

Therefore, you got the error when you do:

```
  systemCommands[0] = new COMMAND("halt", HALT);
```

which tries to call the constructor with prototype: `COMMAND(char*, int);`.